# Setting up Tor Relay on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm having some issues getting my relay up and running with Ubuntu. I have one running on Debian with no issues, so hopefully someone can give me a hand.

I followed the torproject instuctions:
You need to add the following entry in /etc/apt/sources.list or a new file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/:

deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial main

deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial main

Then add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the following commands at your command prompt:

gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -

You can install it with the following commands:

$ apt-get update

$ apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring

I've double checked my version and everything there is correct.

I then edit my torrc

with

`ORPort 443`

`ExitPolicy reject *:*`

`log notice /var/log/tor/notices.log`

`Nickname ****`

But I run the service and nothing populates in the log file (in fact notice.log is never created).

The service is marked as running/ran but then I get the "Interrupt: exiting cleanly" message but I don't know where/why that is coming from.
Has anyone encountered this? And if so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: That line should be `Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log`

Comment: Have you ever felt so dumb you wanted to die? That's me right now. Apparently, my Nickname exceeded the character limit. Thank you though, you definitely solved me problem. ORPort is now reachable.

Answer (score 0):

As my experience has shown - **there's no way to capture all the output data**,especially the crush case ones. Use GNU Screen with `2>&1` and data logging for this - no other way is fully working. Run Tor in foreground in that case

Comment: Why downvote if you don't know what you're talking about? `Log` directive does not capture crush data/trace

Comment: That wasn't I who downvoted.

Comment: @T.J. do you need instructions on how to make it work?

Comment: I figured it out. I starred out my nickname, but it was one character too long, so the torrc wouldn't be validated to even create the log. Thank you for reaching out. My middle relay is now up and running.

Comment: @T.J. but if that was an issue with invalid string - was Tor even starting? Or - if it started - it should point you to exact "bad line number" and say explicitly that it's an error - in stdout in foreground mode(`RunAsDaemon 0`)